# iOS action - how do i get event data from UIAction for a standard UIButton?

Tags: ios, uibutton, uievent

For UIButton, Is there a way on touchDragInside to tell what direction the gesture was in? (up, down, left, right)

```
- (IBAction)buttonTouchedUpInside:(UIButton *)sender forEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
}
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You should to subclass the button and override beginTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:, continueTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:, and endTrackingWithTouch:withEvent:. The logs I put in the code below should get you started with what you want to do.

```
 - (BOOL)beginTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
   NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint([[event.allTouches anyObject] locationInView:self]));
    return YES;
}

- (BOOL)continueTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint([[event.allTouches anyObject] locationInView:self]));
    return YES;
}

-(void)endTrackingWithTouch:(UITouch *)touch withEvent:(UIEvent *)event {
    NSLog(@"%@",NSStringFromCGPoint([[event.allTouches anyObject] locationInView:self]));
}
```

If you're only interested in the overall direction, you can just look at the beginTracking number and the endTracking number, and forget about the continueTracking method.